# sharer.php doesn't shows some other website

Tags: web, facebook-sharer

I have the following -

```
href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.projectpulse.tv"
```

For some reason it goes to some other website.  I have set my title tag, meta description and title tag, thinking that's what it looks for, but I still get the dotster website to show up when I share.  I am not sure if I'm missing something else, could someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into the `og:tags`.  These are tags that help Facebook decide what image and what text to be displayed when sharing content.

You can read more about OpenGraph, the tags and how to use them here:
[OpenGraph Protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)

The tags themselves look something like this:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="YOUR_APP_ID" /> 
<meta property="og:type" content="YOUR_NAMESPACE:recipe" /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="Stuffed Cookies" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/zhen/cookie.jpg" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="The Turducken of Cookies" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/zhen/cookie.html">
```

Once you have implemented the `og:tags` and provided the correct content to the tags you can head on over to the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).  This tool will show you exactly how Facebook views your URL.  If it finds properties missing, or any other related errors, it will also tell you what is wrong.